# Sewn Edges Appear Sharp

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm having an issue where edges that are sewn together using the cloth simulation don't look realistic using the default settings. Specifically, the sewn edges appear sharp.

Below is an example. On the left of the body, you'll see a folded plane connected by edges. On the right, you'll see a cylinder.

[image]

When the cloth simulation is applied, the cylinder appears sooth while the folded plane as a sharp edge where the stitching appears:

[image]

[image]

Is there anyway to control the sewing dynamics for a more realistic look?